# How can I compute angles & lengths of the following tiling shape

Tags: geometry, symmetry, tiling

a while back I created a tile made of arrows: [image]

I did it using a vector graphics software, without really understanding the properties of this shape.

Now, let's say I want to write a program to generate the shape, and not do it manually, how would I go about it?

So far, I managed to figure out some of the shape properties through measuring:
[image]

It is clear that $a=a$ & $b=b$, also, I noticed that a perfect hexagon blocking a perfect hexagon that in turn blocks a third perfect hexagon, define the $``width"$ of the "arrow head" (the image shows it more clearly).

So let's say I'm given the length of the arrow: $x$, how do I represent all the sides & angles with relation to $x$?

Comment: $x$ is not enough to uniquely specify this shape. Can some other properties of the shape (sides, angles) be assumed as given?

Comment: I don't think you can freely change other lengths or angles. I can't prove it, but I got a hunch that changing any property of the shape freely, will break it's tiling ability, or it's symmetry. am I wrong here?

Comment: You are right, I did not consider the tiling ability, which imposes further constraints.

Comment: There are many relations between the edge lengths, which you have already identified, but also the angles. For instance, the angle between the two $a$-lengthed edges must be $120$ degrees because in the tiling, three of them meet at a vertex in the tiling. Similarly, the small and large angles which appear between two $b$-lengthed edges (the ones lying on the axis of symmetry) must add to $120$ as three of each meet at a vertex in the tiling. Finally, the acute and reflex angles appearing between an $a$ and $b$-lengthed edge add to $360$ as is apparent in the tiling.

Comment: right :) but beside knowing angles should add up to 120 degrees or 360 degrees, I can't figure out what exactly is the portion each angle contributes...

Answer (score 0):

Those two numbers $a,b$ are the lengths of two sides of a triangle whose third side has length $\sqrt{3} x / 3$. This is enough to tell you that, within certain bounds, the numbers $a$ and $b$ can be chosen independently, and that all angles are determined by the choices of $a,b$.

First, to justify this statement about the triangle, you need to picture a fundamental domain $\triangle ABC$ for the symmetries of your tiling. In your picture with the colored $a,b,x$ labels, consider light brown colored $x$ segment, oriented towards the right, let its initial vertex be $A$ and let its terminal vertex be $B$. The fundamental domain is an isosceles triangle with base $\overline{AB}$, angles $\pi/6$ at $A$ and $B$, and opposite vertex $C$ with angle $2/\pi/3$. That point $C$ is located in your picture with the colored $a,b,c$ labels as follows: start at $A$, move along the adjacent edge labelled $b$ to its opposite endpoint which I'll denote $D$, then take a sharp left turn and move along the adjacent unlabelled edge of length $a$ to its opposite endpoint which is $C$. You can see, by following these directions in the big picture of the tiling, that $C$ is a point of order 3 rotational symmetry of the picture. The points $A,B$ are each points of order 6 dihedral symmetry.

With this picture of the fundamental domain in mind, you can compute using trigonometry that:
$$\overline{AC} =\sqrt{3} x / 3
$$
You can also see from this description that there is a triangle with one side $AC$, one side $AD$ of length $b$, and one side $CD$ of length $a$.

Finally, using trigonometry you can compute what all the angles have to be. For instance, the exterior angle of the arrow at $D$ is the same as the interior angle $\theta$ of the $ACD$ triangle at $D$ which you can compute with the law of cosines
$$\overline{AC}^2 = \overline{AD}^2 + \overline{CD}^2 - 2 \overline{AD} \, \overline{CD} \cos(\theta)
$$
$$3x^2 = b^2 + a^2 - 2 ab \cos(\theta)
$$
which you can solve for $\theta$.